# The import com.google.api.services.storage cannot be resolved

Tags: google-cloud-storage

```
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
```

What are the JARs to be added and where can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you're trying to use the GCS component of the Google API Client Library for Java. If you're using Maven, it's:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-storage</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev82-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The JAR itself is gonna be at https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/storage/v1/java

These links, as well as Gradle snippets and documentation, are at: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1